# Function is not returning value

Tags: javascript, html

I have basic js script but i cant figure out why is it now working.

User write amout here:

```
<input class="dpinput" id="gvfrom" placeholder="Suma.." type="text" value="">
```

And change value in this form by submiting button in same form

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="gvhere" value="">
<input type="submit" class="pbutt2" value="&#8680;" onclick="go3(); return false;">
</form>
```

JS script is here

```
<script>

function go3() {
   var gvfrom = document.getElementById('gvfrom').value;
   document.getElementById('gvhere').value = gvfrom;
};
 </script>
```

Problem is that form is not submitted (normally is redirected to other site with values). Thanks for any help.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? Basically, after press that button this input `gvhere` will have the entered value from input `gvfrom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "return false;" from submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put `return false`? Try removing it, it will work much better I guess.